# jniavutil.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror

When i run the code from the following link, https://github.com/sagioto/LipReading/blob/master/lipreading-gui/src/main/java/edu/lipreading/gui/MainFrame.java ; I get the following error :

> Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Harish ram\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp13384533628877\jniavutil.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
>       at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:418)
>       at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:368)
>       at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:315)
>       at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avutil.(avutil.java:75)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>       at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
>       at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avcodec.(avcodec.java:85)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>       at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
>       at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avformat.(avformat.java:76)
>       at com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:111)
>       at com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:104)
>       at com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:107)
>       at com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:101)
>       at main.java.edu.lipreading.gui.LipReaderPanel.getVideoFromSource(LipReaderPanel.java:150)
>       at main.java.edu.lipreading.gui.VideoCapturePanel$1.run(VideoCapturePanel.java:89)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I dont understand what is wrong. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score -1):

The code tries to use the [JavaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/) wrapper for FFmpeg ([FFmpegFrameRecorder](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/FFmpegFrameRecorder.java?r=0e256f192bd4239069e2b1a1e45472762865e45f)) you need [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) installed in your system in order to use it.

Take a look at the requirements section at the main page of JavaCV and the [Quick Start for OpenCV and FFmepg](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/#Quick_Start_for_OpenCV_and_FFmpeg) too.

Comment: But which FFmpeg version should i use ?? i'm having Windows 7 / Eclipse Indigo / Opencv 2.4.2 / javacv 0.2

Comment: Read the project main page, please.